# Include SASS variables in an Angular 2 component

Tags: javascript, angular, sass

I'm wondering if i can use sass variables in an Angular 2 component. Something like:

```
@Component({

  selector: 'my-component',

  template: `
    <div>
      <div class="test-div">test div 1</div>
    </div>
  `,

  styles: [
    `
    @import "variables";

    .test-div{
      border: 1px solid $test-color;
    }
  `]

})
```

my file _variables.scss:

```
$test-color: green !default;
```

It seems whatever I try the sass variables aren't recognised.
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Include styles from separate file.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-questions',
  templateUrl: './questions.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./questions.component.scss'],
})
```

Add `_variables.scss` file to component's folder and import it in `questions.component.scss`

```
@import 'variables';

.questions-filter{
  a {
    color: $green;
  }
}
```

It works well for me.

Comment: hey Alex. thanks for taking the time to answer that. this is a solution that seems pretty good to me and it works.

Comment: It works but it will be very to hard to maintain in any project size. See my answer below!

Answer (score 22):

I disagree with the correct answer here is why.

ATM correct answer suggests creating a _variables.scss on each component folder where the variables are needed. This will be very to hard to maintain in any size project unless you have a single component in which case you won't need to import; just use component.scss

There is an option in **.angular-cli.json(angular.json in Angular 6)**, which intends to solve this exact problem, here it is:

```
...
,
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
  "includePaths": [
    "./scss/base"  // BASE SCSS LOCATION
  ]
},
...
```

The base scss location relative path to the current file(.angular-cli.json)
in that location you can add _variables.scss _mixins.scss _anyother.scss

Then in any component.scss you can:

```
@import 'variables';
```

Thanks for your time.

Extra: *By your example, it seems you not using angular/cli to generate components, if that is the case use this ng g c component-name-here*.

Comment: Good answer. you might need to restart your server so it can compile the change in angular.json file.